# Remove text up to Nth instance of pattern match in csv files

Tags: mysql, csv, awk, sed, grep

I'm looking for a way to remove the first `n` lines from `csv` files.

Basically I've been given a dump of several hundred csv files with the task of creating a queryable MySQL database. The files have a legend in non-csv format taking up the first `~10` lines and throw an error when attempting to import to MySQL. The legend is variable in length as not all files have the same number of parameters.

I'm looking for a way to remove the legend and the only pattern I can find is that the first `csv` element is always the second instance of the word **year**.

The files basically look something like this, I want the start of each file to be the second instance of lower-case **year**.

```
Legend:
non-csv text...
year: Year
... etc

(csv format) year, month, day, etc...
```

I've looked at `sed` commands to loop through each file but can't find one that achieves exactly what I want. i.e:

```
find . -name "*.csv" | 
while read filename; 
do 
  sed -n '/year/,$p' $filename > newFile.csv;
done;
```

This removes all text before the first instance of **year** but I'm unfamiliar with `sed` and can't figure out how to make it skip to the second instance. I tried the above in a recursive function but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/year/{c++} c>1' file

(csv format) year, month, day, etc...
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, exactly what I need. I was almost resigned to having to do hours of manual work!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you(*GNU* `sed`):

```
sed ':a;N;s/year/&/2;Ta;s/.*\n//' file
```

This gathers up lines until the second appearance of `year` and then deletes all lines up to but not including the current line.